# Dismiss error when variable is undefned javascript

Tags: javascript

When I run this code

```
return (
          val.ticket.ticketNumber.toLowerCase().includes(inputText) ||
          val.ticket.source.toLowerCase().includes(inputText) ||
          val.ticket.lagoonMaterial.toLowerCase().includes(inputText) ||
          val.ticket.vendor.toLowerCase().includes(inputText) ||
          val.ticket.gallons.toLowerCase().includes(inputText);
        );
```

Sometimes one the properties is missing and that gives me this error

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating
> 'val.ticket.vendor.toLowerCase')

How can I dismiss this property without having to use if statement?

Answer (score 0):

Use [nullish coalescing operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator). It's like an OR (`||`), but it only works for `null` and `undefined` values. The placement of `??` is just like `||`

```js
function getValue(num) {
  return num ?? 'Pass a number';
}

console.log(getValue(5));

console.log(getValue());
```